# Xcode crashing when trying to run on iOS 13.2 device

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

My app runs properly on other devices and in the simulator, but my iOS 13.2 iPhone causes Xcode to crash when it is about to run on the device?

here's my crash log:

```
Process:               Xcode [6201]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               11.1 (15405)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-15405000000000000~13 (11A1027)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       832925179
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [6201]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-10-31 11:09:42.827 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        AE67D298-19BC-5BC6-E2C9-0312CD6CAEE2


Time Awake Since Boot: 1500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        9  Dispatch queue: Mutex to protect _hasPerformedWorkerAction

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
com.apple.main-thread
ProductBuildVersion: 11A1027
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInternalInconsistencyException): Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
UserInfo: (null)
Hints: 
  0: Calling block provided to DVTSyncPerformBlock() here:

  0   DVTSyncPerformBlock (in DVTFoundation)
  1   -[IDEExecutionRunnableTracker executionWantsHold:withError:] (in IDEFoundation)
  2   -[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:] (in IDEFoundation)
  3   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_3 (in IDEFoundation)
  4   __48-[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   DVTDispatchBarrierSync (in DVTFoundation)
  8   -[DVTDispatchLock performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9   -[DVTDispatchLock_Recursive performLockedBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10   __44-[IDERunOperationWorker _startWithRetrying:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEFoundation)
 11   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 12   __DVTDispatchAfter_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 13   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
 14   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 15   _dispatch_source_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 16   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
 17   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 18   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 19   _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 20   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 21   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

Backtrace:
  0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
  2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  3   +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] (in CoreFoundation)
  4   -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] (in Foundation)
  5   -[NSCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:] (in AppKit)
  6   -[NSCell setStringValue:] (in AppKit)
  7   -[NSControl setStringValue:] (in AppKit)
  8   -[IDEExecutionHoldAlertHelper showAlert] (in IDEKit)
  9   -[IDEWorkspaceTabController showExecutionHoldAlertWithError:] (in IDEKit)
 10   __55-[IDEWorkspaceDocument _setupLaunchSessionsObservation]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEKit)
 11   -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
 12   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 13   NSKeyValueDidChange.llvm.18255262684423441536 (in Foundation)
 14   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 15   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 16   _NSSetCharValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 17   -[IDEExecutionTracker _updateWantsHold] (in IDEFoundation)
 18   __37-[IDEExecutionTracker addSubtracker:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 19   -[DVTObservingBlockToken observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] (in DVTFoundation)
 20   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver (in Foundation)
 21   NSKeyValueDidChange.llvm.18255262684423441536 (in Foundation)
 22   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 23   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
 24   _NSSetCharValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
 25   __60-[IDEExecutionRunnableTracker executionWantsHold:withError:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
 26   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
 27   __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke.48 (in DVTFoundation)
 28   DVTInvokeWithLazyFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 29   __DVTSyncPerformBlock_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
 30   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 31   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 32   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 33   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 34   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 35   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 36   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 37   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 38   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 39   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 40   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 41   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 42   main (in Xcode)
 43   start (in libdyld.dylib)

abort() called
```

full log: https://pastebin.com/8aHqMbWn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 11.2 was launched today, 4 days after iOS 13.2.

I was unable to make Xcode 11.2 work with iOS 13.2 devices.

I used AppCleaner to remove every single piece of Xcode from my computer then I downloaded Xcode 11.2 and installed it again.

It is now working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 11.1 doesn't really support iOS 13.2, you should wait for Xcode 11.2 to be released fairly soon by Apple or download the beta version of 11.2 from Apple's site.

Comment: usually the xcode GM supports the latest release iOS though?

Comment: Usually, yes. Was the GM version Xcode 11.2? By now the full version of Xcode 11.2 is available in the App Store.